# FastAPI AWS Lambda cookie response invalid

Tags: authentication, cookies, aws-lambda, fastapi

I am trying to retreive an acces_token cookie from a FastAPI Lambda routine. I used the FastAPI [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-cookies/?h=cooki) to set the response cookie like this:

```
@app.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(response: Response, form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
   access_token = "<access_token>"
   response.set_cookie(key="access_token", value=f"Bearer {access_token}", httponly=True, samesite="none", secure=True)
   return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

If I am running the FastAPI locally with uvicorn the cookie will be received as expected, but using AWS Lambda the cookie value will be changed to:

`"\"Bearer <access_token>\""`

Due to the extra quotes the cookie value is invalid. Why is Lambda changing the value and how can I get rid of the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

After several tries, I figured it out. Removing the "Bearer" resolves the issue:

```
response.set_cookie(key="access_token", value=access_token, httponly=True, samesite="none", secure=True)
```